# Problema ao transformar input text em letras maiúsculas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um `input` e quero que ele permita apenas letras maiúsculas em tempo real.

Esse código aparentemente funciona perfeitamente.

```
$("#texto").on("input", function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

Porém notei um bug e não sei resolvê-lo:

Quando tenho um texto por exemplo "RIO JANEIRO" e quero corrigi-lo para "RIO DE JANEIRO", quando digito qualquer letra no meio da palavra o cursor do input é resetado e vai para o último caractere e então o texto fica assim "RIO D JANEIROE". Reparem que a primeira letra fica no local correto e em seguida o cursor é movido pro final.

Como posso resolver isso?

```js
$("#texto").on("input", function(){

 $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Comment: o "problema" é o evento que você está usando; ao converter os caracteres pra `uppercase` o cursor vai pra o final. Você poderia trocar o evento para o `focusout`, por exemplo. Sim, seria uma gambiarra :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Soluções com `value.toUpperCase` parecem ter um problema que ao digitar no campo o cursor é resetado, essa alternativa de solução trata esse problema:

```js
function handleInput(e) {
   var ss = e.target.selectionStart;
   var se = e.target.selectionEnd;
   e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
   e.target.selectionStart = ss;
   e.target.selectionEnd = se;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTest" oninput="handleInput(event)" />
```

**Fonte:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067218/7558069

Uma alternativa é a solução com **CSS**:

Possui apenas um efeito visual, ou seja, a mudança não persistirá no `POST`.

```css
#InputUpper {
  text-transform:uppercase
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="InputUpper" id="InputUpper" value="teste" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente fazer conforme o exemplo abaixo, trocando o evento `on` pelo `change`, creio que assim funcione do modo desejado:

```js
$("#texto").change(function(){

 $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="texto">
```

Outra possibilidade seria com `css` utilizando a propriedade `text-transform: uppercase`, dai ao digitar o texto já irá ficar em maiúsculo:

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/>
```

Comment: Preciso que o campo fique em maiúsculo o tempo todo, pois esse campo também efetua uma busca conforme vai digitando

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Verifique a segunda possibilidade que postei acima utlizando apenas `css`, creio que isso resolva o problema.

Comment: @Leandro a do `css` é top..